# TYPO3 Indexed Search Pagination not showing next pages

Tags: pagination, typo3, tx-indexed-search

When I search on my website and try to use the pagination it says "no entrys found" (https://www.zeva.org/werkzeuge/suche   search for "test")
How can I fix that?

I tried disabling the searchbar on the top right header and already tried to use the javascript via console. Nothing works

I'm using the standard Fluid Template for indexed search

Comment: I just searched for the word “test” and it gave back at least 10 pages with results. Did you fix it? If yes, what did you do? It might be helpful for someone in the future

Comment: Sorry that I've didn't answered..
No the problem is not solved yet. The pagination is there but when you click on it, you are redirected to the same page but without any results.

Do you now understand my problem?

Comment: Do you have another Idea?

Comment: not really, as indexed search builds it's own paginator via PHP. ;(